# Multiple rows creation - power query excel

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

Team,

I have one table and need to do cross apply to create multiple rows with the help of power query. In VBA i can do this by loops but need to do with power query...

For instance,

Table A  has SLA1 and it is applicable to 3 Depts, so I should get 3 rows. Here all the SLAs will be in vertical and depts will be in horizontal. X will be used to determine applicability of SLA for respective dept. or depts (if X in multiple depts.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With the table in Power Query, select the first column, then click Transform > Unpivot > Unpivot other columns.

Rename and remove columns as desired.

[image]